# Runtime Error handling for @react-three/fiber useTexture

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm using @react-three/fiber's [useTexture](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei#usetexture) to generate a decal for a [three.js](https://threejs.org/) object.

The url for the image file (`fileName`) gets generated dynamically and the image files live on a different server

```js
decal = useTexture(fileName)
```

This works fine as long as the file exists. However, I get a runtime error, if the file is not valid.

```bash
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Could not load https://example.com/files/image: undefined
```

I cannot figure out how to catch/mitigate that error.

Minimal working code sample:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/adoring-dijkstra-mz2hsy

I already tried to wrap it in a `try/catch`

```js
  let decal = {}
  try {
    decal = useTexture(fileName)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Could not load texture', fileName)
  }
```

but that never loads the decal, even if the image file exists and causes a never ending amount of this error:

```bash
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'elements')
    at Matrix3.copy (three.module.js:1425:22)
    at refreshTransformUniform (three.module.js:17783:23)
    at refreshUniformsCommon (three.module.js:17847:13)
    at Object.refreshMaterialUniforms (three.module.js:17806:13)
    at setProgram (three.module.js:19469:27)
    at WebGLRenderer.renderBufferDirect (three.module.js:18762:29)
    at renderObject (three.module.js:19201:23)
    at renderObjects (three.module.js:19183:21)
    at renderScene (three.module.js:19101:48)
    at WebGLRenderer.render (three.module.js:19005:17)
    at render$1 (index-8afac004.esm.js:1506:63)
    at loop (index-8afac004.esm.js:1528:27)
    at sentryWrapped (helpers.js:80:23)
```

And this version (using an empty image in `catch`)

```js
  let decal = {}
  try {
    decal = useTexture(fileName)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Could not load texture', fileName)
decal = useTexture('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=')
  }
```

causes this error:

```bash
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Should have a queue. This is likely a bug in React. Please file an issue.
```

**Update:**
Seems like this [drei issue](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei/issues/1706) is related, but I couldn't fix my problem that way (`ErrorBoundary`) either.

**Udpate 2:**

When I use `TextureLoader` instead of `useTexture`, i.e.

```js
// decal = useTexture(fileName)
decal = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(fileName)
```

then there is just no texture with the faulty url and I get this error in the console:

```bash
console.js:43 THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture marked for update but no image data found.
```

but the site does not crash completely.
So it works better. If I remember correctly though, I used `TextureLoader` at the beginning and then switched to `useTexture`, and there was a reason for it, but I do not recall what that reason was. It also feels like `useTexture` should be the better approach when using  *drei*.